# Can i put Adsense Code in CodeIgniter config.php?

Tags: codeigniter, adsense

I m working in CodeIgniter, Where I want to put my AdSense code in `config.php` file which is common to all pages.

Because I want to load this code base on some condition, For Example: I want to load 250*250 AdSense or 300*400 or I want to put some sort of banner etc *(IN this case I will no longer in need of AdSense)*.

I only want to ask that, can I do so or not?

Comment: you can create your own custom config file and autoload it [Refer this](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/config.html)

Comment: Config Class BCIT Codeigniter http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/config.html

Comment: The @iivannov answer is great, but I'll suggest you to put configuration variables in config ... and keep the main code in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will propose to put you AdSense code in a separate view file under views directory: **application/views/ads/adsense.php**

Then based on your condition you can include it by using the code below directly in all your views.

```
$this->load->view('ads/adsense');
```

You can have different view files for the different sizes or types of ads you want to display. Then you can set in your controller a variable with the type of the ad and load it's own view.

```
$this->load->view('ads/' . $type);
```